Connections between almost discrete spaces and sober/spectral spaces
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
Recall that a topological space $X$ is almost discrete if there is exactly one $p \in X$ that is non-isolated. This question concerns whether a space being almost discrete has any connection to it being sober/spectral. It should be noted that $X$ being almost discrete does not imply it is spectral, as it needs not be compact (say, $X$ is the disjoint union of an infinite discrete space and the Sierpiński space). But does it imply $X$ is sober? Moreover, is $X$ being non-compact the only obstruction to it being spectral? That is, if $X$ is both compact and almost discrete, is $X$ necessarily spectral? Currently, there are no counterexamples to either question on pi-Base. See here and here.
We recall the definitions here: $X$ is called sober if every nonempty closed irreducible (aka hyperconnected) $A \subset X$ has a unique generic point. $X$ is called spectral if it is compact, sober, compact open sets form a basis for topology, and the intersection of two compact open sets is compact.

Yes to both questions.
Let $X$ be almost discrete with the unique non-isolated point being $p \in X$. Let us first show $X$ is sober. Let $A \subset X$ be nonempty and hyperconnected. Then it cannot contain more than one isolated point. Thus, $A$ is either a singleton, in which case it clearly has a unique generic point, or of the form $\{x,p\}$ where $x \neq p$. Note that $x$ is isolated in $X$ and thus also in $\{x,p\}$, so, for $\{x,p\}$ to be hyperconnected, $p$ must not be isolated in $\{x,p\}$, i.e., $\{x,p\}$ is the Sierpiński space with $x$ being the isolated point. But then $x$ is the unique generic point of $\{x,p\}$.
We now in addition assume $X$ is compact. From before, we already know $X$ is sober. We note that any open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ must be cofinite, as otherwise $\{U\} \cup \{\{x\}: x \notin U\}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover. We now consider when exactly a subset $U$ of $X$ is compact open:

If $U \subset X \setminus \{p\}$, then $U$ is automatically open. It is also discrete, so it is compact iff $U$ is finite.
If $p \in U$, then for $U$ to be compact open it is of course necessary that $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p$. Conversely, any open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ is compact. Indeed, let $\{V_i\}$ be an open cover of $U$. Then for some $i_0$, $p \in V_{i_0}$. $V_{i_0}$ is open in $U$, which is itself open in $X$. Thus, $V_{i_0}$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $X$. As we have observed, this implies $V_{i_0}$ is cofinite in $X$ and thus also in $U$. From this it is obvious that $\{V_i\}$ admits a finite subcover.

To summarize, $U \subset X$ is compact open iff either $U$ is finite and does not contain $p$, or $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p$. From this description it is clear that the intersection of two compact open sets is compact, and that compact open sets form a basis for topology.

We make an additional remark that the above implies any compact subset $K$ of an almost discrete $X$ is spectral. Indeed, if $p \notin K$ or $p$ is isolated in $K$, then $K$ is discrete and thus finite. Finite discrete spaces are clearly spectral. If $p \in K$ and $p$ is not isolated in $K$, then $K$ is a compact almost discrete space itself, so $K$ is spectral.
